# Why does perl print "%x" as a numerical value while reading from a file and writing into another file?

Tags: perl, printf

I have this text in file 1:

```
printf ("integer value is %x \n", a);
```

I want to read data from file 1 and write into file 2. 
When I reach this particular line, file 2 appears like this:

```
printf ("integer value is 0 \n", a);
```

Why does it happen? How can I avoid this?

This is how my Perl code looks:

```
while ($line = <$in_fh>) {
    printf $out_fh $line;
}
```

Here, $in_fh and $out_fh are in & out file handles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `printf` interprets `$line` as a format string, and finds `%x` which looks like a token. Use `print` instead.

Answer (score 6):

Because that's what [`printf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html) does. You want [`print`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html).

```
while ($line = <$in_fh>) {
    print $out_fh $line;
}
```

If you want to keep using `printf`, you need to use

```
while ($line = <$in_fh>) {
    printf $out_fh "%s", $line;
}
```